# PLSQL Using CR character in CLOB

Tags: plsql

We are reverse engineering a vendor deployment product and have been able to generate a script to update product that includes a combination of CR and CRLF characters (not sure why vendor uses both but we need to match their result).  The issue is when we plan this script it converts the CR to CRLF automatically whether executing the script through SQLPLUS or running it in SQL Developer UI.  Looking for a way to allow a CLOB update to update field with CR characters (the CRLF update part appears to be working fine).  We've been fighting this for sometime and researched it extensively with no luck.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Henry Wood.  Is there any chance you could include an example of the input data and the problematic output, or the update you are using that does not giving the expected result?

Comment: It is a little difficult to show as the (CR) symbol is removed on copy paste.  I'm using the following to compare whether two tables have the same CLOB  values.  When I pull the results out they are the exact match except when I show symbols in notepad++ I see the insert done through tool has CR and we have CRLF.  --0 means match while -1 means no match
select
   a.businessruleguid,
   dbms_lob.compare(nvl(a.xmldata,'Null'),nvl(b.xmldata,'Null')) 
from 
   table1
    Inner Join table2
where
   dbms_lob.compare(nvl(clobcoloftable1,'Null'),nvl(clobcoloftable2,'Null')) = -1;

Comment: Looking at SQL before inserted in notepad++ the clob shows CR symbol but after executed then pulled back out the CR changes to CRLF.  Wish I could show image as that would be more helpful as showing CR verse CRLF in notepad++ is the only way to see difference.  If I copy the text in this window they look the exact same as carriage return is removed.

Comment: Even so, an example we could try ourselves would be useful.

Comment: Ok, script below creates a test table and does several different kind of test inserts.  Test 2 is the one to focus on, this inserts several carriage returns but when you copy and paste into Notepad++ you see carriage return plus linefeed.  Looking for a way to insert just the carriage return with no linefeed.    CREATE TABLE TEST("COL" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE));
  
Insert Into TEST (col)
Values ('test2' || chr(10) || chr(10) || chr(10));

Insert Into TEST (col)
Values ('test3' || chr(10) || chr(13));

Commit

Select *
From Test;

Drop Table TEST;

Comment: Thanks @HenryWood .  In your `TEST` example, I take it that both the entries for `test2` and `test3` are followed by `chr(13)`, in Notepad++?  Can you try an experiment for me and let me know the result?  Can you please try calling `SELECT DUMP(the_problem_column) FROM your_table WHERE some_condition_to_get_a_problem_row;` and let me know the result?  This will give a look at the state of the saved data, to help determine if it is being inserted incorrectly, or if fetching from the IDE/Notepad++ is the problem.  Thanks

Comment: Typ=1 Len=8: 116,101,115,116,50,10,10,10, that is a helpful command and based on that test it looks like it is inserting just CR fine and notepad++ is adding symbol.  Still have mystery as to why vendor solution pulls out and shows CR symbol in notepad++ while my insert does not.  That is very helpful though, thx.

Comment: Went ahead and used python script to export to notepad++ and can't see CR from there.  I use the same export on the clob I'm trying to replicate and it does show the CR symbols.  Wish I could run the DUMP command on the clob I'm trying to match but it looks like it doesn't work on CLOBs.